# Not able to achieve a network packet size greater than 16kb for BCP load to Azure SQL DB from databricks cluster

Tags: pyspark, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-databricks, bcp

I am trying to load data from azure databricks cluster to a azure managed sql server instance through BCP utility. Here I am using Apache spark + Python for data processing and writing the final dataframe as a text file and loading the same to azure sql server DB through bcp utility. The issue is even though I am specifying parameter "-a 32678" to set network packet size to 32kb , still I could achieve only 16 kb in real.

I would like to know is there any cluster level limitations for network packet size. I am using a standard_DS5_v2 databricks cluster

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the pattern.  Why not dump data into your data lake and load to Azure SQL DB with Data Factory?  That would be more conventional and allow you to power down your Spark cluster.  Maybe I’m missing something.

Comment: My notes also say 16192 is the max packet size for Azure SQL DB. I believe I saw that in an error at one point. So I think it’s a limitation with the destination. I doubt the packet size will make a huge difference because latency should be low if Databricks and Azure SQL DB are in the same region.

Comment: @wBob It's True . Issue is we are writing the delta lake and SQL server. And this Azure  SQL server is a temporary platform for mirroring it temporarily to an On-prem one. And we have predefined classes for BCP handler already written on our framework which I am inheriting to save time since it's a temporary station until we decommission the On-Prem one. So only I was checking on how and all I can tune it. Though pre-ordering the cluster index column is the one really helped me here by using an ORDER hint with BCP.

Comment: @GregGalloway That's a new info , then why SQL server BCP document saying BCP packet size can range from 4kb to less than 63kb. May be for On-prem only ? Actually I am lucky to get some performance boost with using the data file which is pre-ordered on clustered index column and using and ORDER hint with BCP utility command .

Comment: @akhilpathirippilly my understanding is that on-prem SQL Server can do 32KB

Answer (score 0):

> The maximum network packet size for encrypted connections is 16,383 bytes.

[Configure the network packet size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-network-packet-size-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16)